# How can I restore a bacpac file to SQL Server linux docker container?

Tags: sql-server, linux, docker, docker-compose, sql-server-linux

I am trying to setup an integration testing environment for Docker. We need to restore a bacpac to our `mssql-server-linux:latest` image so we can run tests based on the dataset.

My compose file looks like:

```
version: '3'

services:
    projectweb:
        image: projectweb
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Project\Dockerfile
        depends_on:
            - db
    db:
        image: "microsoft/mssql-server-linux"
        environment:
            SA_PASSWORD: "MyVerySecurePassword"
            ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"        
        volumes:
            - ./database:/tmp
```

I don't need the changes to the database to be persisted past the life of the container. I just need to script getting the data into it. I don't have a lot of experience with docker or SQL Server for Linux. I assume I need to wait for the container to be initilizsed and DB setup and started, then execute a script that reads the database bacpac from tmp folder. As far as I understand I should use sqlpackage but this doesn't [appear to be in the container](https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-docker/issues/135)? Do I need another container with this SSDT/sqlpackage in it? Can I install splpackage into the container?

What is the best way to do import bacpac data?

Comment: `sqlpackage.exe` requires windows so you'll need a Windows container (or other Windows machine) to deploy a bacpac to SQL Server on Linux or Linux container. You could restore from a database backup instead of using a bacpac to avoid the Windows dependency.

Comment: Ok. bak file won't work for us really - as it is SQL Azure for the data - and pretty sure we can't get bak file from it. However guess there must be other option instead of bacpac

Comment: @DanGuzman  Just so I am clear - there used to be a way to do this via sqlpackage on linux? http://reverentgeek.com/sql-server-for-linux-how-to-move-a-database-from-one-docker-container-to-another/ that MS have currently removed according to the github thread?

Comment: There may have been a Linux version available at one time but it's not currently available. Microsoft is beefing up open-source cross-platform database tooling support but it's still work in progress. I expect sqlpackage or it's equivalent to be available for Linux in the future but when it's anyone's guess as to when. For now, Windows is needed for sqlpackage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has now been resolved. Microsoft have a proper sql package for Linux. This can be installed into a custom image. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage?view=sql-server-2017